# Moldable wire mesh alternative to chicken wire?

Tags: wiring, product-recommendation

Someone in my family wishes to make a custom dress form out of chicken wire as described [here](http://syzygyofworlds.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-construct-personal-dress-form.html) and as shown in the picture:

[image: chicken wire dress form]

(Reasons for choosing the chicken wire approach: Reviews indicate that the commercial Dritz dress form and similar products don't adapt well to posture eccentricity, e.g. kyphosis due to osteoporosis.  Chicken wire is moldable.  Note, we have rejected other DIY approaches such as duct tape, paper tape, padding and plaster so let's not rehash those decisions here.)

Question: Is there another type of moldable wire mesh that might work even better?

Bonus question: the creator of the chicken wire approach finished up by wrapping the whole thing with a single layer of duct tape.  As a final step, is there something that can be painted or sprayed over the whole thing to give it more rigidity?

Pretend the tag is "wire" -- it keeps converting to "wiring" -- sorry.

Comment: For the bonus question, I'd skip the duct tape and use paper mache, which is a much more compatible base for a paint or sealer layer. Duct tape is shiny and plasticy and very hard to get paint to stick to. Or use gaffers tape or athletic tape rather than duct tape, if wanting to use a "sticky-tape similar to duct tape" but with a more paintable surface.

Comment: Chicken wire probably be the easiest type to mold of the screen type wires.  There are different size spacing  to choose from.  Would try the paper mache that @Ecnerwal mention, since tape will probably change the shape of chicken wire, easy to bend/might not hold shape if picked up wrong.

Comment: Okay, so paper mache.  Flour paste, rather soupy, dip strips of paper in, wiping the excess off between two fingers, three layers minimum?

Comment: @crip659 - Can you give me a link to the type of chicken wire you think would work best?  Then I'll match it up to something I have in my basement or at the DIY store.

Comment: Some chicken wire will have smaller openings than shown(about finger size).  Don't know which be better, but think the small size would be slightly stiffer(hold shape better).

Comment: There's a reason I didn't ask at Crafts.  People here know more about wire and similar materials, and a dress form is a type of *tool*.

Comment: @aparente001, your question has nothing to do with Home Improvement - and don't start with the "but it's DIY !!??!!?" - this is the "DIY **Home Improvement**" stack. See https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic as well as the big banner at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean by "better", but probably not. Chicken wire is moderately cold worked steel , easily bendable but strong enough to hold the shape. I have seen aluminum mesh but it has significantly less stiffness to hold shape. I use chicken wire and a couple different light gage steel wire fence products to make cages around plants for protection from deer. You may find steel fencing that is "better " for your purpose; stiffer but needs more force to bend. Any fencing I have seen has larger spaces between wires than chicken wire. For a non-adjustable dress form, you could apply fiberglass sheet with polyester liquid to harden it ( often called epoxy). One source would be auto body repair supply. It could be made very ridgid depending on the weight of fiberglas chosen.

Comment: Polyester and epoxy are entirely different products, though both are commonly used with fiberglass. Polyester is cheaper and stinkier, epoxy more expensive and less stinky (other than the 5 minute sort, which is unsuitable for this application.)